# Is it possible for a file system minifilter driver to interfere with NTFS compression?

Tags: windows, drivers, ntfs, compression

On my work laptop I was running low on disk space and attempted to compress a folder using NTFS compression. The file properties dialog *acted* like it was compressing the folder but after it finished I noticed that the "Size on Disk" reported was still the same. The contents of this folder was highly compressible text files so it should have had no problem compressing them.

I noticed this behavior both before and after my employer upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. So I know it's not a behavior specific to Windows 10.

I've searched for what could cause this behavior. NTFS compression can be disabled through group policy settings but I've already ruled that out. According to Microsoft's documentation this would have caused the option to compress a file or folder to be disabled rather than "go through the motions" with no effect.

While searching for possible causes I discovered that there are no less than 15 minifilter drivers installed on my computer. Most I've identified as either part of the Windows operating system, antivirus, encryption or monitoring software. The rest I can't identify but were likely installed for similar purposes.

What I'm wondering is if it's possible for one or more of these minifilter drivers to prevent NTFS compression from working.